# Views image field

Tags: 7, views, media

I'm trying to add inline styling to my Drupal image using the image field under view. No matter what method I try, nothing is working. I've run out of options.

Any help?

Below are a few code examples of what I've used:

```
<img src="[field_image_upload]" height="150" style="margin: 5px; margin-right: 15px; float: left;">

[field_image_upload]

[<img src="[field_image_upload]" height="150" style="margin: 5px; margin-right: 15px; float: left;">]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are generally not the best way to go. You will be happier in the long run if you apply CSS classes to your Views and handle the styling in external CSS.

That said, you could try checking the box that says "Exclude from display. Enable to load this field as hidden. Often used to group fields, or to use as token in another field." on your `field_image_upload` field.

Then create a new field of type "Global: custom text" and build your custom markup in that field, using the token as you have in your first example above:

```
<img src="[field_image_upload]" height="150" style="margin: 5px; margin-right: 15px; float: left;">
```

If the token is not available for use, make sure that you rearrange the field order in your Views display so that the image field comes before the Global custom text field.

**UPDATE:**

You *can't* use inline CSS to do what you're trying to do:

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-06-12/d7-how-do-i-use-inline-css-in-global-custom-text

> View Global custom text field uses `filter_xss_admin`, so you can't include inline css in this field. One solution you can build is overriding `view-view-field.tpl.php` for this field specifically and in template file you can theme it as you like.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your solution but it's still not working.

Comment: Do you see any output? Look at the HTML source of the page.

Comment: This is the output:   " height="150">. I've checked the source of the page to try and figure out what was wrong but still no luck. At this point I'm going in circles.

Comment: Is `" height="150">` really the only output on the line? It is very difficult to know what is going on without more context. Please paste a few more lines of the HTML output (not in the comments, but in the original question above) so that we can see a bit more of what is before and after the code in question. After pasting the code, highlight it and click the `{}` to format it as code.

Comment: Yes that's honestly the only thing that's outputting. Here's my code I put in

Comment: <img src="[field_image_upload]" height="150" style="margin: 5px; margin-right: 15px; float: left;"> and  " height="150"> is the results

Comment: See my revised answer above. You can't use inline CSS. You'll need to learn how to override the default template file with a custom `.tpl.php`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for checking this out for me.

Comment: Honestly, it will be easier for you to just apply classes to your views and define the styles in an external stylesheet. This is how most people do it. If you already understand how to write inline styles, it should not be hard to learn how to define styles in external CSS. At least, it's easier than learning Drupal template overrides, which are not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my custom text code

```
**<img src="[field_image_upload]" height="150" style="margin: 5px; margin-right: 15px; float: left;">**
```

and here's what comes out from that code:

```
" height="150">
```